# Angular Route problems with cordova wrapped app

Tags: angular, cordova, angular-routing

I am trying to wrap my existing angular app into a Cordova FWK.

My baseHref must have to be `"baseHref": "/appname"` to match with server side `Oauth` rules.
With angular simple start script works fine but wrapping it into a `cordova` app and then run with `Browser` (`cordova run browser`) platform the baseHref not works.

If I launch `http://localhost:4200/appname` I get this error: `Cannot GET /appname`.
If I launch `http://localhost:4200` it works and launch the remote oauth login page but when the login process succesful ends and redirect I get the error message : `Cannot GET /appname/callback`

It is necessary to configure some additional stuff into angular to make it works the angular routing logic into a `cordova` project?